# Use table.insert with dynamic variable names

Tags: lua, lua-table, dynamic-variables

I got a question on how to use dynamic variable names with the table.insert function in Lua.

I want to create some tables with dynamic variable names and afterwards access those tables using table.insert function to fill them with values, however, I am unclear on how to access the newly created table inside of the table.insert function.

My code so far looks like this:

```
local attributeNames = {"attribute1","attribute2","attribute3"}
local attributes = {}

for k, v in pairs(attributeNames) do
        // If attribute name equals name of type then create a new table with 
           that type name
        if(string.match(v, type)) then
          attributes[v] = {}
          currentAttribute = v
          break
        end
      end
// Insert values into the table with that type name, here I do not get how to call 
   the table of name "attribute1" for example to fill it with values
table.insert (attributes[currentAttribute], values)
```

Any help is highly welcome! :)

Comment: But... you just wrote the code for how to call it. Does `currentAttribute` contain the string `"attribute1"`? Then your code ought to work.

Comment: You might want to change `type` to something different since that name refers to a builtin lua function `type` to avoid confusion. Maybe `attribute_type`

Comment: You are right, it actually works ... I tried the code again, and it works for me now, guess I was just too tired testing it yesterday, thanks for your comments, @greatwolf I will change the variable to something else than type, didn't know that this was a builtin lua function, thanks! =)